# Can a malicious contract consume users' ram?

Tags: smart-contract

Can an evil contract fill users' ram with junk data?

Comment: I think would be nice if EOS need support some kind like "ram limit"(similar gas limit on Ethereum) when submit a transaction to prevent malicious contract eat up all user's ram.

Comment: I see the max_net_usage_words and max_cpu_usage_ms setting in the transaction, but no ram limit, I think your suggestion is great

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/571)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but it can only consume the ram of users who send it actions. Users should avoid sending actions to contracts which don't provide a way to release users' ram.

Comment: but many users don't review the code, they just use the dapp, I think @user1627's suggestion below is a good solution

Answer (score 0):

I am confused because you are asking questions without distinguishing between users and contract deployers.

If your question implies a contract deployer, it is to use the RAM of the account that deployed the contract.

RAM is purchased and used by contract writer(deployer), and it is entirely the contract writer's fault that they are misused within their limits.

Of course, it would be nice to provide a way to make sure your network can respond to these mistakes.